# Service worker fetch event for POST request get body

Tags: javascript, service-worker

How can I capture the body of POST request in a Service Worker. I am sending authentication parameters in the POST request, so I want to intercept the fetch request in service worker and show results from IndexDB. 
Following is the code from my service worker

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
let cloned = event.request.clone();
console.log(cloned.json()); //<<- This line returns error : TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Request': body stream is locked
let response =  new Promise((resolve)=>{
  let key='mykey'; //Genereate from body, so read body
  let stored = localforage.getItem(key);
  if(stored){
      resolve(stored);
  }else{
    resolve(fetch(cloned).then(res => res.json()).then(res=>{
         localforage.setItem(key,res);
    }));    
  }
})

event.respondWith(response);

})
```

*p.s : please ignore syntax errors if any.*

Comment: There really should be a JavaScript-setting: "ps_please_ignore_syntax_errors_if_any"! That would make life so much easier! :D ;-)

Comment: did you solve? capture formData or Body?

Comment: Yes, the request is a stream as the data is still arriving at service worker, you can capture the data request.body.json() , request.body.formData() gives the params be sure to use it under a promise. I will share full code to answer this question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since request body is ReadableStream, for the reasons @Mr.Vibe mentions in the above comment it cannot be accesed through `event.request.body`, One way to access the body is by using `await event.request.json()`, However one should notice that once the request body is read it cannot be reused as body of a request as it throws an error like `This ReadableStream is disturbed (has already been read from), and cannot be used as a body`. So its better we clone the request and then access its body as in `await event.request.clone().json()`, So that later on we could use the original request unharmed.

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", async (event) => {
 let clonedBody = await event.request.clone().json();
  ...
})
```

Comment: Yes, I used this to resolve the issue. forgot to update here.